# Fill HTML Login Form and Download Data

Tags: html, r, httr

I am trying to download [VIIRS Night Lights](https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/vnl/) data from the Earth Observation Group by making a POST request. You can specifically check the download page [here](https://eogdata.mines.edu/nighttime_light/monthly/v10/). The first time one tries to download the data on a browser it asks you to create a new user/login after which it starts the download. Here's the R code that I'm trying to use but I'm unable to download the `.tgz` file that I want.

```
library(httr)
url = "https://eogdata.mines.edu/nighttime_light/monthly/v10/2015/201502/vcmslcfg/SVDNB_npp_20150201-20150228_75N060E_vcmslcfg_v10_c201504281527.tgz"

POST(
  url = url,
  encode = "form",
  body = list(
    "username" = "INSERT_USERNAME",
    "password" = "INSERT_PASSWORD",
    "kc-login" = "Log In"
  )
) -> res

out <- content(res)
```

Instead, I'm getting an HTML with the login page content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an **access token first**.
Check the sample code on their site: https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/register/#programmed_access 
*(NOTE: I did not try it... Let me/us know, if you encounter any issue with it.)*